# SaveAs method saves workbook as ReadOnly

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote code that saves the book in a specific format. After saving, the book is only available in read-only mode. What could be the error?

```
    Sub SaveAs()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim relativePath As String
    relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (I had to change the name of it tho as it was a reserved word), assuming the workbook that is open at the time is already saved somewhere and it already in XLSM format. That information is not in your question in your case. Are you trying to save a new workbook that has never been saved yet?

Comment: Hello! I apologize for the late response. I am trying to save an workbook with a replacement, in the same directory. When I open an excel workbook, I get a notification that the excel workbook is only available in read only mode.

Comment: @Foertsch Didn't the message say that the workbook is open in another session? If yes, you may have a not visible Excel session, which remained in this stage when Excel crushed after a specific error. I would suggest you to use the Task Manager and check how many Excel sessions appear there...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, you are absolutely right, the excel session was active.